# Programme not giving the required output

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where I am supposed to do the following.

1. Write a program that asks for an employee's salary and years of service.
2. If the employee has greater than 10 years of service. They get 10% raise. Between 5 and 10 years the raise is 5%. Everybody else will receive 2% raise.
3. The employee's yearly bonus. Is 500$ fir every 2 years of service.
4. Display the calculated information in a clear professional manner.

I wrote the code below as a solution to the assigned problem; however I keep getting false output for everything. I tried to debug the program to figure out the problem, I read the book and looked in the web, but I couldn't find out what's wrong.

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>


using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::setw;
using std::setprecision;
using std::fixed;
using std::right;
using std::left;
using std::setfill;

//function prototypes
void GetInput(double & salary, int years_service);
void CalcRaise(double & salary, int years_service);
int CalcBonus(int years_service);
void PrintCalculations(int years_service, double salary, int bonus);

int main() 
{
    //variable diclerations
    double salary = 0.00;
    int years_service = 0;
    int bonus = 0;

    //function calls
    GetInput(salary,years_service);
    CalcRaise(salary,years_service);
    CalcBonus(years_service);
    PrintCalculations(years_service,salary,bonus);

    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}

//prompts the user for input
void GetInput(double  &salary, int years_service)
{
    cout << "Enter Salary: ";
    cin >> salary;
    cout << "\nEnter years of service: ";
    cin >> years_service;
}

//calculates the raise
void CalcRaise(double & salary, int years_service)
{
    double raise = 0.00;


    if (years_service > 10)
    {
        raise = salary * (10 / 100);
        salary = salary + raise;
    }
    else if (years_service >= 5 && years_service <= 10)
    {
        raise = salary * (5 / 100);
        salary = salary + raise;
    }
    else
    {
        raise = salary * (2 / 100);
        salary = salary + raise;
    }
}

//calculates the bonus
int CalcBonus(int years_service)
{
    int bonus = 0;

    bonus = (years_service / 2) * 500;

    return bonus;
}

//outputs the results of the calculations
void PrintCalculations(int years_service, double salary, int bonus)
{
    cout << setw(18) << left << "Years of Service" << setw(16) << left << " Salary after raise" 
        << setw(8) << left << " Bonus\n";
    cout << setw(15) << setfill(' ') << right<< years_service 
        << setw(18) << setfill(' ') << right << salary << setw(8) << right << setfill(' ') << bonus;
}
```

=========================

```
The Output:

Enter Salary: 4000

Enter years of service: 7
Years of Service   Salary after raise Bonus
               0              4000       0
```

Comment: Try using `double` literals in calculations like this: `(10.0 / 100.0)`

Comment: You need to pass `years_service` by reference to `GetInput`. `void GetInput(double  &salary, int& years_service);` Right now, `years_service` gets locally modified in `GetInput` and remain set to `0` in `main`.

Comment: Start with something small and simple that works perfectly (like a program that prints "5"). Add complexity a little at a time (like making it take user input for the value of `salary, then print that value). Develop new functionality in isolation, and integrate two functions only when they both work perfectly. Small steps.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I am grateful for the help and advise. I will use them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is here:

```
void GetInput(double  &salary, int years_service)
```

You pass `years_service` as a value. That will simply copy the 0 that you had before. Then you never read it, but write to it. The original value will of course not be overwritten.

You should pass by reference instead.

```
void GetInput(double  &salary, int& years_service)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of changes are required to make anything out of  your code.

**Change 1**

```
void GetInput(double & salary, int years_service);
```

should be changed to

```
void GetInput(double & salary, int &years_service);
```

**Change 2**

You could change the return type of CalcBonus from int to double so that
you won't lose precision, ie

```
int CalcBonus(int years_service)
{
  int bonus = 0;
```

should be changed to

```
double CalcBonus(int years_service)
{
  double bonus = 0.0;
```

**Change 3**

You are not storing the returned value from `CalcBonus` anywhere.
Inside `main` function declare a double variable for bonus, say **bonus**.
and capture the value returned from the `CalcBonus` function like this.

```
double bonus;
bonus = CalcBonus(years_service);
```

That should be it.

Comment: Please remember though that Stack Overflow is not an online free fix company for your code. Try to capture the logical errors to the best of the capacity before you post the question here,

Comment: Thank you for your help that worked. As well, thank you for the hint regarding stack overflow.